# Extracting the relationship between entities in Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I want to extract the complete relationship between two entities using Stanford CoreNLP (or maybe other tools).

For example:

> Windows is *more popular than* Linux.
>
> This tool *requires* Java.
>
> Football is *the most popular game in* the World.

What is the fastest way? And what is the best practice for that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: hey, are there any NLP libraries that is capable of converting a text into subject-predicate-object triples ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably looking for dependency relations between nouns. Stanford Parser provides such output. Have a look [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-dependencies.shtml). You can combine what Pete said (i.e. the POS graph) with the dependency graph to identify what relationship (for example, direct object or nominal subject, etc.) a pair of nouns (or noun phrases) share.

Answer (score 8):

[ReVerb](http://reverb.cs.washington.edu/) focuses on **Open IE**. You can start by reading their paper "[Identifying Relations for Open Information Extraction](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2145596)" and checking the [demo](http://openie.cs.washington.edu/) site.

Comment: the link for the paper may be dead, can you pls check it again?

Comment: Done updating the link.

Comment: I've made a simple example, in Python, on how to use those PoS-tags to extract relationships: http://davidsbatista.net/blog/2017/05/08/ReVerb/

Answer (score 3):

So you are looking for the verb phrase that links noun phrases. That is actually dead simple in Stanford CoreNLP. Just run it through the pipeline and traverse the POS graph to get what you want. You will have to come up with ways of handling complex sentences and of course you will want to use the co-reference system to deal with anaphora.

It is non-trivial so can you break your question down somewhat to a question that can be answered? If your question is, is this possible to do? Then the answer is yes. If it is "how can I do it?" then I suggest you start using the system and answer that question yourself.

Comment: What do you call a POS graph?

Comment: (ROOT
  (S
    (NP (PRP$ My) (NN dog))
    (ADVP (RB also))
    (VP (VBZ likes)
      (S
        (VP (VBG eating)
          (S
            (ADJP (NNS bananas))))))
    (. .)))

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Stanford Relation Extractor](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/relationExtractor.html) which is part of the coreNLP pipeline.  It is specified by "relation" and at the very least has dependencies on "ner" and "parse", the Named Entity Recognition and Parser annotators.

Answer (score 0):

If you more or less want to extract the part of the sentence connecting the entities, a simple way to do this is using spacy and textacy. If you use java I would recommend the openIE tool from CoreNLP. You can also use CoreNLP with python via stanza's CoreNLP client. If you tell me a bit more about the programming language you'd like to use and/or your project, I am happy to give a more detailed description of the necessary steps.